# Update table row if row exist in some table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM plan_acl 
WHERE plan_id = (SELECT id 
                 FROM plan 
                 WHERE unicateHash = '2xxxxxxxxxxxxMcxXqZoydkOltnadm1Uf' LIMIT 1)
```

Which return c as count. Like this:

```
c = 1
```

or

```
c = 0
```

I want update table if `c = 1`. How Can I do this?

I try:

```
SELECT IF(SELECT COUNT(*) AS c 
          FROM plan_acl 
          WHERE plan_id = (SELECT id 
                           FROM plan 
                           WHERE unicateHash = '2xxxxxxxxxxxxMcxXqZoydkOltnadm1Uf' LIMIT 1).c = 1, "YES", "NO");
```

But I am getting error.

Whats is wrong?

Comment: hint: use Update to update.   Also please post error.

Comment: What do you want to update?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to update table plan. Set isActive to false

Comment: @JoshAdams hint: use brain before you post comment, this is only example.

Comment: ERROR: #1064 - Vaše syntaxe je nějaká divná blízko 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM plan_acl WHERE plan_id = (SELECT id FROM plan WHERE un' na řádku 1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the table, you can use syntax like this:

```
UPDATE plan_acl a
    SET isActive = 0
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM plan p
                  WHERE p.id = a.plan_id AND p.unicateHash = '2xxxxxxxxxxxxMcxXqZoydkOltnadm1Uf' 
                );
```

Note that your method of using `limit 1` and `=` does pretty much the same thing, but `EXISTS` is built into the SQL language for exactly the purpose of testing whether a row exists in a table.